# IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of model class nic.mams.model.InspectionReport.inspectionReportId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
   public class Application implements java.io.Serializable {
 private long applicationId; 
 private String policeStation;
 private String shortestRoute;

private Set inspectionReports = new HashSet(0);

public Application() {
 }

 public Application(long applicationId, Applicant applicant) {
 this.applicationId = applicationId;
 this.applicant = applicant;
 }

 public Application(long applicationId) {
 this.applicationId = applicationId;
 }

 public Application(long applicationId,String policeStation,String shortestRoute,
 Set inspectionReports){

 this.applicationId = applicationId;
 this.policeStation=policeStation;
 this.shortestRoute=shortestRoute;
 this.inspectionReports=inspectionReports;
}

public long getApplicationId() {
 return this.applicationId;
 }

 public void setApplicationId(long applicationId) {
 this.applicationId = applicationId;
 }

public String getPoliceStation() {
 return this.policeStation;
 }

 public void setPoliceStation(String policeStation) {
 this.policeStation = policeStation;
 }

public String getShortestRoute() {
 return this.shortestRoute;
 }

 public void setShortestRoute(String shortestRoute) {
 this.shortestRoute = shortestRoute;
 }

public Set getInspectionReports() {
 return this.inspectionReports;
 }

 public void setInspectionReports(Set inspectionReports) {
 this.inspectionReports = inspectionReports;
 }

}
```

And the corresponding HBM is

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 18 Jun, 2012 3:04:42 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="nic.mams.model.Application" schema="public" table="application">
<id name="applicationId" type="long">
<column name="application_id"/><generator class="increment"/>
</id>

<property generated="never" lazy="false" name="policeStation" type="string"><column name="police_station"/></property>
<property generated="never" lazy="false" name="shortestRoute" type="string"><column name="shortest_route"/></property>

<set cascade="all,delete-orphan" fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="inspectionReports" sort="unsorted" table="inspection_report">
<key><column name="application_id"/></key>
<one-to-many class="nic.mams.model.InspectionReport"/>
</set>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The InspectionReport class is

```
    public class InspectionReport implements java.io.Serializable {

 private long inspectionReportId;
 private Application application;
 private Date inspectedOn;

 public InspectionReport() {
 }

 public InspectionReport(long inspectionReportId,Application application) {
     this.inspectionReportId = inspectionReportId;
     this.application = application;
     }

 public InspectionReport(long inspectionReportId) {
 this.inspectionReportId = inspectionReportId;
 }

 public InspectionReport(long inspectionReportId,Application application,Date inspectedOn) {

 this.inspectionReportId = inspectionReportId;
 this.application = application;
 this.inspectedOn = inspectedOn;
 }

 public long getInspectionReportId() {
 return this.inspectionReportId;
 }

 public void setInspectionReportId(long inspectionReportId) {
 this.inspectionReportId = inspectionReportId;
 }

 public Application getApplication() {
 return this.application;
 }

 public void setApplication(Application application) {
 this.application = application;
 }

 public Date getInspectedOn() {
 return this.inspectedOn;
 }

 public void setInspectedOn(Date inspectedOn) {
 this.inspectedOn = inspectedOn;
 }


}
```

The curresponding HBM is

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 14 Nov, 2011 5:11:45 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="nic.mams.model.InspectionReport" table="inspection_report" schema="public">
        <id name="inspectionReportId" type="long">
            <column name="inspection_report_id" />
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="application" class="nic.mams.model.Application" fetch="select">
            <column name="application_id" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="inspectedOn" type="date">
            <column name="inspected_on" length="13" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I have executed the code below ,I got an exception
Application application=new Application();
.................................
 saveOrUpdate(application);

The exception is

```
2013-11-15 10:50:01,346 ERROR [org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3) IllegalArgumentException in class: nic.mams.model.InspectionReport, getter method of property: inspectionReportId
2013-11-15 10:50:01,347 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3) org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of nic.mams.model.InspectionReport.inspectionReportId; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of nic.mams.model.InspectionReport.inspectionReportId

2013-11-15 10:50:01,347 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:488)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,349 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,349 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,349 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,349 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,349 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,349 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at nic.mams.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:46)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,350 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,350 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,350 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at nic.mams.jstl.tag.FilterConfig.doFilter(FilterConfig.java:33)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,350 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,350 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,351 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,352 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,352 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,352 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,352 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3) Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of nic.mams.model.InspectionReport.inspectionReportId; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of nic.mams.model.InspectionReport.inspectionReportId

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:659)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:378)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.merge(HibernateTemplate.java:769)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at nic.mams.hibernate.QPQLMLInspec2Hibernate.saveOrUpdateInspec(QPQLMLInspec2Hibernate.java:2035)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at nic.mams.serviceimpl.QPQLMLInspec2serviceImpl.saveOrUpdateInspec(QPQLMLInspec2serviceImpl.java:338)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at nic.mams.web.QPQLMLFirstInspecController.processFinish(QPQLMLFirstInspecController.java:1211)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractWizardFormController.validatePagesAndFinish(AbstractWizardFormController.java:656)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractWizardFormController.processFormSubmission(AbstractWizardFormController.java:493)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:265)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:861)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:795)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,353 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   ... 28 more

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3) Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of nic.mams.model.InspectionReport.inspectionReportId

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:195)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:206)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3619)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:145)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:714)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:696)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:268)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,354 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:291)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:239)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:192)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:319)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:265)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:242)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:192)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:459)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:318)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:167)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,355 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:81)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,356 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:704)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,356 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:688)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,356 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:692)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,356 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$23.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:772)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,356 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:373)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,356 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   ... 40 more

2013-11-15 10:50:01,357 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

2013-11-15 10:50:01,357 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,357 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,357 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,358 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

2013-11-15 10:50:01,358 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.162.9.129-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the value of applicationId is null. Because the primitive long cannot handle a null, it will throw a error if it is a null. Try changing the type to Long which is the object implementation of long.